# How to force a filter to be stateless in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am maintaining a site developed with angularjs. There is one filter in the site, that takes two parameters. One of the parameters (the second) is a array.

I can guarantee that this parameter will never mutate. It is treated as a inmutable array. If for some reason it changes, a simple reference check would be enough. (and I am almost certain that will never mutate in the life of the view where the pipe is used)

The other parameter is a int.

But the filter is re-evaluated in every digest. Looking at the documentation it is said that filters are stateless, unless configured otherwise, but with few exceptions.

My case is one of the exceptions, because one of the parameters is an Array. According to the documentation, the exceptions are in place because it would be difficult to track changes in objects. But I know that my object will not mutate!

In Angular (newer, not angularjs) it would work because it compares references. Is there a way to force the same behavior for one filter in angularjs?

In case it helps, the code of my filter is something like this:

```
.filter("findById", function() {
    return function findById(id, items) {
        console.log("Evaluating")
        var result = items.find(function(item) { return item.id == id });
        return result ? result.name : "";
    }
})
```

It is the items array, that I can guarantee that is inmutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one time data binding, when using the filter in the view, like below

```
{{abc|findById:id:(::idsArray)}}
```

Hope, it works, and tell me if it did...

Comment: Even when one time binding is a good idea, my angular version seem to only allow that sintax right after the curly braces as in {{:: <expression> }}, when trying to use your syntax it gives a compile error with this message: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/error/$parse/syntax?p0=:&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=29&p3=filters%20%7C

Comment: Looking into the issue i found this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13595 that seem to state that you can not use one-time-binding with filters arguments.